# What's difference between "t1.__index = t2" and "setmetatable(t1, {__index = t2})"?

Tags: oop, lua, lua-table, metatable

I seen this things in others code, and if I understood correctly it should be used like this:

```
t1 = {}
t1.__index = t2 --1

function t1:new()
    local new = {}
    setmetatable(new, {__index = t1}) --2

    new.something = 0

    return new
end
```

But what they really do and why have different way of writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are written differently because they do different things.

```
t1 = {}
t2 = {a = 20}
meta = {__index = t2}
setmetatable(t1, meta)
print(t1.a) -- prints 20
```

Note how there's 3 tables here: `meta`, the metatable, `t2`, which stores the key `a` and `t1` which we want to set to look up missing keys in `t2`.

The metatable only serves teh purpose of controlling the behavior of `t1`, but, to use less tables, people often use the fallback table (`t2`) as the metatable (`meta`) so it becomes something like

```
t1 = {}
t2_and_meta = {a = 20}
t2_and_meta.__index = t2_and_meta
setmetatable(t1, t2_and_meta)
print(t1.a) -- prints 20
```

Comment: So I tried in online IDE. What I want to do is class inheritance, and `setmetatable(Class, {__index = InheritedClass})` working perfectly. Is this right way to do it? http://tpcg.io/cOapGQ

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to do it, but you should still probably play around with metatables a bit to really get how they work. They are one of, if not *the* most powerful tool in plain lua, in my opinion.